# Instance variable 'variable' accessed in class method error

Tags: objective-c

I have a variable declared in the header file :

@interface

```
int _nPerfectSlides;
```

and

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) int _nPerfectSlides;
```

and I have a method that I declared in the header :

```
+ (void) hit;
```

The method has the following code in it :

```
+ (void) hit {
    NSLog(@"hit");
    _nPerfectSlides = 0;
    [_game showHit];
}
```

now for some reason I get the error "Instance variable '_nPerfectSlides' accessed in class method" error and it seems like I cant access any variables inside the method. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you meant to make this an instance method, change that + to -.

Comment: Yea I tried that before posting, it fixed this issue but when I try calling the method from another class it crashes... what shall I do?

Comment: Create an instance of the class and call the instance method on that instance…

Comment: You seem not to have grasped the core concepts of OOP. Have you assimilated docs like this one? http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html

Comment: @Cyrille you are right, I am new to OOP tbh, used to structured coding. I am reading a few docs around the net and trying to figure it out and also shape up my OOP. but thanks anyways

Answer (score 25):

**1. For** `+ (void)hit`:Only have access to the **`self` object.**

--**Step 1:** Remove follwing line from header file

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) int _nPerfectSlides;
```

--**Step 2:**

- Add `int _nPerfectSlides` in your class file globally..
- That means declare before `@implementation`

Eg: In `.m File`

```
#import "Controller.h"
int _nPerfectSlides // Add like this before @implementation

@implementation Controller
```

---

**2. For** `- (void)hit`:Only have access to the **instance methods**

Answer (score 9):

An instance variable is, as its name suggests, only accessible in the instance methods (those declared with `-`). Class methods (declared with `+`) have no access to instance variable, no more than they have access to the `self` object.

Comment: ok so how can I create a class method to access it from other classes while I have access to the instance variables?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Either you change your `+ (void) hit` into a `- (void) hit`, or you declare `_nPerfectSlides` on a global level, outside of your class' `@interface`.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but it still comes up. Try making it a static. Here's I'm altering the code a bit to make it increment.

```
// Hit.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Hit : NSObject
+ (void)hit;
@end

// Hit.m

#import "Hit.h"
@implementation Hit
static int val = 0;
+ (void)hit {
    val += 1;
    [self showHit];
}
+ (void)showHit {
    NSLog(@"hit value: %d", val);
}
@end

//main.m

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Hit.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        [Hit hit];
        [Hit hit];
        [Hit hit];
    }
    return 0;
}
```