# Access instance variable via static method

Tags: objective-c

When I run this :

```
@interface Database : NSObject {
      sqlite3 *database;
}

+(void)openDatabase;

@end



@implementation Database

+(void)openDatabase
{
    NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databaseNameandPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/DatabaseSnax.sqlite",docDir];
    NSString *databasePath=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:databaseNameandPath];

    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error when open the database");
    }

    [databasePath release];
}
```

I have this error: `instance variable database accessed in class method`

How I can solve this issue and I need to keep my method (open database) as a static method so I can use it by class name, for example:

```
[Database openDatabase];
```

Comment: Please use tags to indicate which language this is (Objective-C?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Instance variable 'variable' accessed in class method error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016904/instance-variable-variable-accessed-in-class-method-error)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will indicate the programming language in the next times :) Yes it's Objective-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One cannot possibly access instance variables from class methods. You may declare a global variable, however:

```
static sqlite3 *database;
// ...
+ (void) openDatabase {
    sqlite3_open(filename, &database);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi H2CO3, Thank you a lot, it is working now .. I know that I can not access any instance variable from class methods, but what I want is how to do this, and your answer helped me ... thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to access `database` from a class method ([which are different from instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053592/objective-c-class-vs-instance-methods)).

Change that declaration from:

```
+ (void) openDatabase;
```

to

```
- (void) openDatabase;
```

and instantiate your `Database` object via the traditional `alloc` + `init` and you'll be on your way.

I like H2CO3's answer too (and +1 to him), but my answer (which is what most people have to do with Objective C objects) may be more practical for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Of course, and it's more elegant, and we don't like global variables. I just decided to write this as he wrote he needed to keep the method static.

Comment: Good point (that he wanted to keep the method static). We don't know what he's up to, but in general, I can't imagine why he'd want to do this statically... unless maybe he's mixing a lot of C++ and Objective C (yucky yuck).

Comment: Thanks Michael Dautermann, you and H2CO3 are right, but I need this because I used the sqlite database in many places, and insert, select and delete from the database, therefore I expected that this way is the best way, if you have any suggestions to enhance my code I will be appreciate you ... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

For reference, `static` means different things to different people/languages. Objective-C being mostly C plus a bunch of syntax enhancements, the keyword `static` in Objective-C has the same meaning as it does in C, which relates to the visibility of the symbol with respect to linking. This is subtly-but-importantly different from how Java and C# use the word static.

Objective-C doesn't have syntax for declaring "static" (in Java/C# parlance) or "class" variables. The runtime has "support" for them (witness the existence of: `class_getClassVariable`) but there's no syntax to declare them, so it's sort of a dead end. (If I had to guess, I'd bet that this feature exists in the runtime to support bridges to other languages/runtimes that use static/class variables.) As other people have suggested, the common way around this is to use global variables (or function statics (`static` in the C linkage sense.))

Comment: +1 for addressing some of the misconceptions embodied in the question.

Comment: However, "static" in general means a class method in OO languages. And one can distinguish between class methods and vars/functions declared with the "static" keyword. It seems that the author of this question actually understands it.

Comment: @H2CO3 The asker is clearly using the keyword `static` in the Java/C#/"class variable" sense. Your answer uses the keyword `static` in a C context (and the use of the C `static` keyword in your answer is orthogonal to the fact that it's a global variable -- it would still be a global variable without the `static`). That's why I bothered to mention it.

Comment: I know it would be a global variable nevertheless, it's just for making it "internal".

Comment: Sounds like everyone's on the same page. :)