# Returning an NSString through a static method

Tags: objective-c, static

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective C Static Class Level variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063229/objective-c-static-class-level-variables)
>   [Instance variable 'variable' accessed in class method error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016904/instance-variable-variable-accessed-in-class-method-error)

I have:

```
+(NSString *)getUsernameString
{
    return usernameString;
}
```

`usernameString` is an NSString declared in the interface and as a property.
I get the error `instance variable 'usernameString' accessed in class method`

What am I missing for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You declare it as `static NSString *usernameString;`

Comment: In the header? That doesn't work